# Implementing galary like view

Tags: android, gallery

[image]
The requirement I have to implement is to create special views that look similar to a gallery.But it has more functions in the project, more details can be hidden after this view  being created. My question is how to create a view like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Coverflow.

There's no inbuilt widget, luckily [this](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) guy has written a nice implementation for it.

Comment: @Flexo, I saw that, I apparently added some junk to it. Fixed now, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one [Coverflow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

This guy is really great programmer who made this. He gave every type of Coverflow solution in this implementation.